# Is it ok to use the log-normal approximation for incidence rates?

Tags: poisson-distribution, lognormal-distribution, incidence

I have a dataset with counts of events, population and time, and need to perform a meta-analysis of incidence rates (IRs) per person-month.

By assuming random effects (thus, allowing for heterogeneity of variance across studies), and a Poisson distribution for counts of events (the parameter estimate for each study being the number of events itself: let's define it $n_i$), I get that the variance of the logarithm is equal to $\frac{1}{n_i}$, thus its standard error to $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_i}}$.

The point is: can I build the CIs based on the logarithm? To put it another way: can I use the log-normal approximation for rates (and thus, given the exposure is considered as constant, for the number of events, that I assume to be Poisson-distributed)?

Answer (score 0):

generally yes, but I feel specifying the data structure and the model would help. I have understood you have a model like:

events ~ population + time + (1| person)?

also, you should prefer a square root transformation if you have zero counts. Anyway, after calculating the CIs in the log scale, you would exponentiate the limits of these intervals to transform them back to the original scale of the rates.

Comment: Thank you. My viewpoint is that the number of events has a Poisson distribution, with $\lambda$ given by the product of contact rate and person-months. I don't have the issue of $0$ events: in fact, the lowest number of events in my dataset is $25$.

Comment: then log transformation is the right thing

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide a reference to defend such approach in case of criticisms?

Comment: No. I was just referring to the fact that strictly positive and large variables can usually be modeled as Gaussian after a log transform. If  is large, the Poisson distribution approximates a Gaussian (i.e., no log needed). But I could not find some proof e.g. that under some conditions the log of the Poisson approximates the Gaussian.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow the logNormal distribution makes me feel "safer" since the IR range is forced to remain among positive numbers, and symmetry wrt the log-transformed values seems to me a more realistic assumption than wrt untransformed values.

Comment: Yes. I would log-transform, and check the qq plot for the residuals. This reference is not specific for poisson distributed values but it night help: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/00045632211050531

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Your suggestion seems perfect for a regular dataset. In my case, observations are rates (or, better saying, pairs “event counts/exposure”) supposed to differ across studies (that’s why a random-effect model). Thus, by assuming that each single study has a Poisson distribution, I use the event counts to estimate the parameter, and calculate the IR (by dividing for the exposure) and its estimated standard error based on that. 
Maybe one should simulate, for each paper, from the estimated distribution, and see whether the log-Normal approximation is acceptable.